# Humble business student - msgbox failing - SOS

Tags: excel, vba, loops, for-loop

The last line is causing some trouble.

```
MsgBox ("Book Code = " & ISBN & vbNewLine & _
        "Book Title= " & title & vbNewLine & _
        "Unit Price= " & title & vbNewLine & _
        "Quanity = " & UnitCost & vbNewLine & _
        "Quanity = " & CustomerInput & vbNewLine & _
        "Final Price = " & (Format(CustomerInput * UnitCost), Currency))
```

Comment: Can you please explain your problem in detail?

Comment: For some reason the last line is causing problem requesting an "expected ')'"

Comment: 3 and 3 :( thanks in advance

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something meaningful. *Humble business student* is irrelevant noise, as is *SOS*. *msgbox faling* is pretty vague as well. Your title should explain the actual problem you're having or question you're asking in a way that will have meaning for a future reader looking for a solution to their problem as they scan a list of search results. *failing* isn't a problem description until you include information on what *failing means specifically. Neither is *causing some trouble*. In what way does it fail? Do you get an error message? If so, what is that message?

Answer (score 2):

Move the close-parenthesis after `UnitCost` in the `Format` statement to the end, and `Currency` in the format statement needs to be a string (i.e: in quotes):

```
MsgBox ("Book Code = " & ISBN & vbNewLine & _
    "Book Title= " & Title & vbNewLine & _
    "Unit Price= " & Title & vbNewLine & _
    "Quanity = " & UnitCost & vbNewLine & _
    "Quanity = " & CustomerInput & vbNewLine & _
    "Final Price = " & (Format(CustomerInput * UnitCost, "Currency")))
```

Although the above works, you can omit some of your parentheses, and possibly make the code a bit easier to understand:

```
MsgBox "Book Code = " & ISBN & vbNewLine & _
    "Book Title= " & Title & vbNewLine & _
    "Unit Price= " & Title & vbNewLine & _
    "Quanity = " & UnitCost & vbNewLine & _
    "Quanity = " & CustomerInput & vbNewLine & _
    "Final Price = " & Format(CustomerInput * UnitCost, "Currency")
```